# Como definir o local do diretório "resources"?

Tags: java-ee

Estou criando um projeto em Apache Wicket e como sou novo nisso, estou tentando definir `background-images` e pegar algumas funções JavaScript do Bootstrap.

O problema é que eu não estou conseguindo definir o caminho das imagens no HTML e nem nos arquivos CSS. Tento por `'./resources/img/imagem.jpg'` só que mesmo assim ele não consegue achar. Tem algum truque para isso?